# setting position with three.js and CSG

Tags: javascript, three.js, csg

when i use this as code for a cube and a sphere which cuts some part of this cube out:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="csg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://chandler.prallfamily.com/threebuilds/builds/r46/ThreeMin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ThreeCSG.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

var projector = new THREE.Projector( );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
renderer.setSize(800, 640);

document.getElementById('viewport').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    35,
    800 / 640,
    1,
    10000
);
camera.position.set(5, 1.8, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

var cube = THREE.CSG.toCSG(
    new THREE.CubeGeometry( 2, 2, 2 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0)
);
var sphere = THREE.CSG.toCSG(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.4, 16, 16));
var geometry = cube.subtract(sphere);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    THREE.CSG.fromCSG( geometry ),
    new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
);
scene.add( mesh );

renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="viewport"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I now set the position of the cube? Do I need something like cube.CSG.position.set or is there a special method with the CSG library to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call a function after setting the renderer, like:

```
animate();
```

Define it like:

```
function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    cube.position.x = your_value;
}
```